# Importing Manufacturers' logo from PS 1.6 to PS 1.7

Tags: web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I'm importing Manufacturers from PS 1.6 to PS 1.7 by using the Webservices of PS 1.6:

```
        $params = [
                'resource'      => 'manufacturers',
                'contentType'   => 'JSON'
            ];
        $ps16manufacturers = json_decode($this->ps16Client->get($params))->manufacturers;
        foreach($ps16manufacturers as $ps16manufacturer) {
            $params = [
                'resource'      => 'manufacturers',
                'contentType'   => 'JSON',
                'id' => $ps16manufacturer->id
            ];
            $ps16manufacturersObject = json_decode($this->ps16Client->get($params), true)['manufacturer'];

            $ps17Manufacturer = new \Manufacturer();
            $ps17Manufacturer->hydrate($ps16manufacturersObject, \Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
            $ps17Manufacturer->force_id = true;
            $ps17Manufacturer->add(false);


        }
```

It works: in my PS 1.7 (which runs this code), I have imported the Manufacturers of the PS 1.6 by using this Webservice.

However, I would want to import the logo of the PS 1.6 Manufacturers into PS 1.7 too.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Solution (NB: here, `$ps17Manufacturer->id` = PS16 Manufacturer's ID since I used `force_id = true`, see the OP):

```
$tmpfile1 = '......../img/m/' . $ps17Manufacturer->id . '.jpg';
$ps16image = $this->ps16Client->get([
    'resource'      => 'images/manufacturers/' . $ps17Manufacturer->id
]);                     
file_put_contents($tmpfile1, $ps16image);
```